# React-Leaflet: Invalid LatLng object

Tags: javascript, node.js, leaflet

I am trying to take JSON data from a websites API onto my leaflet app through node.js.
The error being thrown by React dev tools seems to point towards my server-side code:

> Error: Invalid LatLng object: (5.45467472, 2014-09-23 21:08:57)

```
   42 | fetch(API_URL)
   43 |    .then(res => res.json())
   44 |    .then(Sessions => {
 > 45 |      this.setState({
^  46 |        Sessions
   47 |      });
   48 |    });
```

I believe that this issue could be to do with my formatting of my data in my schema within my Sessions file:

```js
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  name: Joi.string().min(1).max(100).required(),
  address: Joi.string().min(1).max(500).required(),
  latitude: Joi.number().required(),
  longitude: Joi.number().required()
});

//Post method
  const { name, address, latitude, longitude } = req.body;
    const Session = {
      name,
      address,
      latitude,
      longitude,
      dates: new Date()
     };
   Sessions.insert(Session).then(insertedMessage => {
         res.json(insertedMessage);
   });
```

However I have tried editing the data, changing the schema and removing required values to no avail.

Comment: did you notice the longitude looks like a date?

Comment: @jorg That was the first issue I checked but it seems that all of my longitude parameters are declared correctly within my server file and JSX file